# Save key-value pair in .net profiles

Tags: jquery, asp.net, profile

I have a requirement in which user should have the option to save the selection of items made in a listbox. Does it makes sense to use .net's `profiles` in this case?

For example there are 10 items in my listbox, user clicks on the `save as template` button. An input is shown asking for the `save as template's` name. User enters the name of the template and clicks `save` button. The 10 selected items in the listbox should be saved as strings in the user's `profile` and the key should be the templates name, that is entered by the user.

Next time when the user logs into the application, He/She should be able to see the templates saved in a dropdown and the selection should load the items in the listbox.

Does using profiles help in this case? Or should I go with the traditional saving options available?

Comment: Do you think your list is logically a part of the user profile?

Comment: Yes, the selected items are the users preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Profile Provider, part of the ASP.NET security etc? If so I would just add those Preferences to the User's record.

Comment: I found that it was easier just adding the additional profile related properties to the User data, less setup and just uses the existing User infrastructure.

Comment: How would I add and retrieve multiple preferences with different keys?

Comment: My suggestion is to just add additional columns to your Users table, which eliminates the use of the Profile provider. SO its not based on Keys etc, the preferences are just stored as columns in the users table (where you use your existing Data Access) rather than storing this data in XML or however the profile provider does this by default (which in my opinion is not good)